# Changing the default installation directory?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, application

Is there a way to change the directory where applications are installed? I mean instead of  `/usr/bin` can I change the settings to install them at `/usr/local/bin` or something like that, as long as they are in the **PATH** variable?

Currently using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

If the solution depends upon the package manager, is there any generic approach? Which configuration file(s) should I target?

Comment: Please provide more details. What distribution, package manager, etc. Btw why do you need this? I don't see the point in it. Anyway, if you do, you violate the FHS.

Comment: @psimon I have edited the question

Comment: Can you shed some light on why you want to do this? It sounds a little bit like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: I am running out of space on the root partition, but i had created a separate partition for /usr/local. if ican switch to that partiiton for installing files, it would be really useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Short answer:

No.

#### Long answer:

When installing packages through your package manager (`apt`, which relies on `dpkg`), the files in the .deb archive get extracted and moved to the place they are supposed to be. Configuration files go to `/etc`, binaries to `/usr/bin` or other bin dirs, libraries to `/lib`, etc. The standard that specifies which file goes where is the FHS (File Hierarchy Standard). If you make changes to the installation directories, you will most likely violate this standard. Anyway, `dpkg` has an `--instdir` option, but it would mess up things if used globally.

#### Answer to your REAL problem:

As I read in your comment, the reason you want to do this is because you've run out of space on your root partition, but you have still plenty of it under `/usr/local`.

Changing the installation directory is not a solution, you should repartition your hard drive. You can resize partitions if you don't want to reinstall the system (which is not necessary at all). Try booting a live partitioning system such as GParted if you prefer graphical tools (for the command line, check out `parted` and `fdisk`).

The other solution (I would prefer this since it allows more flexibility in the future) is to set up [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29). LVM stands for Logical Volume Management, which allows (apart from other awesome features) resizing partitions without losing data and having to repartition your hard drive. It is a bit too complicated to be explained here, but there are great guides on it. One such is [HowToForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm) and you can also check out the relevant [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM) page.

Comment: does this still apply to all modern package managers?

Comment: yes, this still applies to all modern package managers.